# Изменение размеров индикатора QCheckBox

Tags: c++, qt

Требуется изменить размер поля для галочки в QCheckBox. Пробовал сделать это с помощью настройки стиля:

```
::indicator{height: 30px; width: 30px;}
```

В дизайнере размер индикатора меняется, но при запуске приложения остается размер, заданный по умолчанию.

Как можно изменить размер индикатора?

Comment: Попробуйте в Qt Creator запустить qmake (или вообще все пересобрать). Возможно, `ui` файл не транслировался в c++, поэтому изменений в приложении не увидели

Comment: @gil9red Я пересобирал проект уже несколько раз, вплоть до того, что просто удалял целиком папку, куда выполняется сборка ,чтобы гарантировано избавиться от старых файлов

Comment: в коде у вас нигде потом не вызываеся setObjectName (или другие функции изменяющие подтягивание qss стилей)?

Comment: вот я сейчас взял пример tabdialog и сделал `readable->setStyleSheet("::indicator{height: 30px; width: 30px;}");` - работает, попробуйте

Comment: @goldstar_labs Не для этого окна, но вызываются

Comment: @PavelGridin Попробовал. Не работает. Увеличивается размер поля, в котором расположен индикатор, но сам индикатор (квадратик ,в котором ставится галочка) не меняется, остается стандартного размера

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов, у вас наверное стиль Windows, задайте в программе Fusion если у вас Qt5

Comment: @PavelGridin А можно поподробнее? Раньше не доводилось работать со стилями, так что я не очень понимаю, о чем Вы говорите.

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов, прямо в самом начале программы делаете `app.setStyle("Fusion");`, где app это QApplication

Comment: @PavelGridin Спасибо, сработало. Будьте добры, оформите все Ваши рекомендации ответом, чтобы я мог его принять.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Qt стиль виджета задаваемый функцией `setStyleSheet` - является своего рода рекомендацией для конкретного стиля программы - `QStyle`. Некоторые стили, особенно системно зависимые `Windows`, `Macintosh` не могут отработать установку некоторых свойств.

Поэтому лучше использовать стили полностью выполненные средствами Qt. Это `Fusion` для Qt5 и `Cleanlooks` для `Qt4`, которые точно отработают такие вещи как

```
setStyleSheet("::indicator{height: 30px; width: 30px;}");
```

Пример установки стиля программы:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication application(argc, argv);
    application.setStyle("Fusion");
```